# After Android Studio update: Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated my Android Studio and now my project won't build anymore. I get following error:

```
Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'App' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the  method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

I didn't change anything, everything worked properly before the update. Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ochs.pipette"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

And here's the other one:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix the problem, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`runProguard` has been renamed `minifyEnabled`. See [the changelog here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) for confirmation - version 0.14.0 (2014/10/31) of the Android Gradle plugin made the swap.

[image: Screenshot showing change location in IDE]

Answer (score 34):

[image]As @stkent said, `runProguard` has been renamed to `minifyEnabled` in version 0.14.0 (2014/10/31) of Gradle.

To fix this, you need to change `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled` in the **build.gradle** file of your project. For example,

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false // Does not exist anymore...
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

would be replaced by

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

You can see other issues [here](http://tools.android.com/knownissues) but this worked for me.

Comment: You mean the build.gradle file that is in the app folder, not the build.gradle file that is at the project's top level. N'est-ce pas?

Comment: It's what I meant. Tout à fait!

Answer (score 1):

**runProguard** has been renamed to **minifyEnabled** in version 0.14.0 (2014/10/31) of Gradle.

To fix this, you need to change runProguard to minifyEnabled in the **build.gradle** file of your project.

[image]